# Incremental sync does update properties in user profile, full sync works - SP13

Tags: sharepoint-server, ups

I have updated a user’s properties like title and address in the AD and run an incremental synchronization of the user profile but the users profile in SharePoint does not updates.  If I run a full sync the properties are updated without any problem. What can be wrong?

Comment: What patch level is the farm at? There have been a few fixes for this over the years.

Comment: The farm has the December 2020 patch installed.

Answer (score 0):

When ever you make changes like "**changing the mapping of property or adding a new mapping or removing,or applying exclusion filter**". You have to run the Full sync followed by an Incremental sync.